# automatic bill number generation in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

In my project I need to generate bill number automatically.

My database is mysql.

I am getting the default value 0 from the column 'bill_no' and increment that value. It's working fine, but my problem is it is incremented up to 10. After that it is not incremented.

What is the reason? please let me know,thanks

My code is:

```
 <%
    connection=DBCreation.getConnection();
      Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
     resultSet= statement.executeQuery("select max(diag_pt_bill_no_v) from diagnostics_details");
     if(resultSet.next())

     {
         System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1));
        i=resultSet.getInt(1)+1;
     }}catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    %>
    <form action="diagnosticsinsert" method="post" name="form">
    <table><tr>
     <td><label class="red">Bill No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type=text name="bno"  placeholder="Bill No" size="17px" value="<%=i++%>"
    </td></tr>
</table>
 <td><button name="save"  id="save" style="width: 80px; height: 30px;font-size: 15px;" value="Save" accesskey="S" onclick="getTotalTests()">Save</button>(Alt+s)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

    </form>
```

Comment: What did happen after 10? Not updating after 10 means ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: successfully 10 is inserted into database and  next max value it shows 9 so based on my code it is incremented to 10 so it gives error Duplicate entry 'new-10' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 2):

check if any max value set to your text box....

Comment: successfully 10 is inserted into database and next max value it shows 9 so based on my code it is incremented to 10 so it gives error Duplicate entry 'new-10' for key 'PRIMARY'